# Rails 3 render partial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that uses partials and in development everything works great but in production I am getting the error

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

I checked my production.log file and this is the error I am receiving

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):

Here is the lines that are causing the problems

```
<%= div_for blog do %>
```

and here is whats causing that file

```
<%= render :partial => 'blogs/blog', :locals => {:blog => @profile.blogs.last}%>
```

here's the entire error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
1: <%= div_for blog do %>
2: <p>
3:   <b>Title:</b>
4:   <%= blog.title %>
app/views/blogs/_blog.html.erb:1:in 
app/views/profiles/show.html.erb:22:in
```

any ideas on how I can resolve this error?

Comment: Are you 100% sure in your production environment that `@profile` actually has any `blogs`? If it doesn't, then you may be settings `:blog` to `nil` when calling your partial.

Comment: Yes I am in production environment and no the profile does not have anything unless the user creates it but you should be able to see the profile page if there is nothing listed. Am im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively calling `nil.last` which will throw this kind of error.

Use a conditional to render the partial *only if* `@profile` contains blogs:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'blogs/blog', :locals => {:blog => @profile.blogs.last}) if @profile.blogs.present? %>
```

Or, what I would do, use a partial. In your view:

```
<%= blogs_or_message %>
```

In a partial:

```
def blogs_or_message
  if @profile.blogs.present?
    render(:partial => 'blogs/blog', :locals => {:blog => @profile.blogs.last})
  else
    "No blogs found" # <= simple error message instead of nothing
  end
end
```

Comment: can I also do something like `<% if #{model} nil? %> create something <% else %> partial here <% end %>` or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Couple gripes with this answer:  1) It's not the call to `last` that's crashing, but a call to `model_name` (Rails tries to give these DIVs IDs like "blog_42"), and 2) Adding the conditional to the render call means you have to add it to every render call to that partial - better to put it in the partial itself.  The `blogs_or_message` setup, though, is a nice touch - good call on that one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that Rails isn't being smart and skipping that DIV if `blog` is `nil`.  Here are a couple possible workarounds:

If you really only want to render a single blog:

```
<% div_for(@profile.blogs.last) do %>
    ...whatever...
<% end if @profile.blogs.last %>
```

Or if you want a DIV for every blog, you shouldn't need the conditional, since `@profile.blogs` will give you an empty array, and Rails knows what to do with that:

```
<% div_for(@profile.blogs) do %>
    ...whatever...
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it's not skipping the div_for, it is not working because I have yet t create anything but if I create a conditional statement like described above is it a safe way to go?

Comment: @coletrain - Yep.  The `if` applies to the whole function call, including the block (like: `(div_for(x) do ... end) if y`), so the function (and thus the block) will only get called if there's a blog to render.

Comment: Also check out the `blogs_or_message` function in gg_s's answer.  It can be a helper function or a conditional in the partial - whichever - but it's good to have some sort of "No blogs?  Let's make one!" message instead of just emptiness.